# Pass function as an argument in a function javascript to NPAPI

Tags: npapi

On javascript Object i am invoking 
obj.requestFileSystem(LOCAL,5*1024*1024) . This method is implemented in PlainNAPI Plugin , now i have to pass one success callback to this function as follows......

obj.requestFileSystem(LOCAL,5*1024*1024,initFS); // initFS is  a function in javascript that is an argument to the success callback .
In NPAPI  it is an object when the requestFileSystem is completed  then initFS function in javascript  should be called. How to return from NPAPI plugin to javascript  and to execute initFS function.

```
function initFS(fs) {
alert('Inside the initFS');
alert(fs.root.getFullPath);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please don't tell me what you're actually doing with this plugin, since it sounds like it's something akin to giving people access to things from a web browser that could easily be abused by someone else.

Basically a function is just an NPObject when it gets to your function inside NPRuntime; to call the function you just do a NPN_InvokeDefault on that NPObject.

Note that you must be on the main thread in order to call nearly all NPN_ functions.

---

EDIT: So if you have to do the callback from a different thread then your easiest solution is to use [NPN_PluginThreadAsyncCall](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/NPN_PluginThreadAsyncCall); basically you create an object to hold the data you need and call PluginThreadAsyncCall with that pointer as the void* parameter and it will get passed to the function you specify.

Make sure that A) the pointer will still be valid, and B) your function is able to free that memory after it runs. From the callback function you can call NPN_InvokeDefault safely.

Not that [NPN_PluginThreadAsyncCall](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/NPN_PluginThreadAsyncCall) doesn't seem to work on Safari 5.1 anymore. If you need that support or if what I've explained doesn't make sense you might want to consider using [FireBreath](http://www.firebreath.org) to build your plugin; it does all of this for you.

Comment: Thanks Taxilian  i am able to get the function as an object in NPAPI After Getting it i am executing one function in separate thread and in main thread calling NPN_InvokeDefault.After returning to browser the result it hangs till it doesn't get the response. Where to use NPN_PluginThreadAsync  so that browser ui  doesn't hangs and asynchronously i can execute other functions.

Comment: It is just an experiment for me , no any plans to share code on web.Just to check can we do operations on local files via NPAPI Plugin.

Comment: Edited my answer to add some details on how that works; note that that is really a different question, so if this question is answered it would be a good idea to mark the answer correct and ask another question (particularly since I think there are other discussions of cross-thread calls here on stackoverflow)

Comment: @r_tex I just looked and realized I've answered several of your questions; you have not yet marked *any* answers to your questions. There is an outline of a checkmark to the left of the answer under the upvote/downvote answers; when someone has answered your question, please mark it as the correct answer by clicking on that checkmark so it turns green. If you never do this people won't want to help you anymore.

Comment: Thanks taxilian i got it , marked it as green , sorry i didn't know i have to mark it when someone answers to the question.

Comment: I didn't understand a word of that.  This is a different question, create a new question for it where you can explain things clearly.  I'll see it, as will others who may be able to help. Note, though, that the correct link for info on the call is https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/NPN_PluginThreadAsyncCall